# Remove connected components below a threshold in a 3-d array

Tags: python, post-processing, numpy-ndarray

I am working on 3-D numpy array in python and want to do post-processing on CNN output of Brain Tumor Segmentation images. We get a 3-D (208x208x155) numpy array with values as 0/1/2/4 for each pixel. I want to remove the connected components with a threshold less than 1000 for better results.

I tried erosion-dilation but don't get good results. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so shrink and grow will, as you realised yourself, not be the way to approach this problem. What you need to do is [region labelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling), and it seems that [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) has a method that will let you do that for nd images.

I assume that by threshold less than 1000 you mean sum of the pixel values in the connected components.

Here is an outline of how I would do it.

```
from scipy.ndimage import label

segmentation_mask = [...]  # This should be your 3D mask.

# Let us create a binary mask.
# It is 0 everywhere `segmentation_mask` is 0 and 1 everywhere else.
binary_mask = segmentation_mask.copy()
binary_mask[binary_mask != 0] = 1

# Now, we perform region labelling. This way, every connected component
# will have their own colour value.
labelled_mask, num_labels = label(binary_mask)

# Let us now remove all the too small regions.
refined_mask = segmentation_mask.copy()
minimum_cc_sum = 1000
for label in range(num_labels):
    if np.sum(refined_mask[labelled_mask == label]) < minimum_cc_sum:
        refined_mask[labelled_mask == label] = 0
```

Comment: Hey. So I tried the above implementation but, there comes an error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'unique'. 
So I tried by passing the tuple as a numpy array but the same error comes. Can you help further?

Comment: My fault, I forgot that the skimage region labelling and the scipy region labelling worked a bit different. I've edited the code now.

Comment: Thank you. I do get another ValueError: 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'.
It is for this line: 'refined_mask[labelled_mask == label] < minimum_cc_sum:'

Comment: That was yet another silly error that I have sorted out now

Comment: Thank you. This has helped my project.